# Preview file with vim

Tags: vim, console

I'm looking for a way to automatically preview a file with vim. The command should open vim, without clearing the screen, bypass any questions (e.g., due to concurrently open files with other instances of vim), display the file, and quit vim without clearing the screen.

This would make vim work similarly to ''cat'', except that it would use the default options in .vimrc to process the tabs, would apply file-specific color formatting, etc. It's ok if it only shows the part of the file that would fit within the height of the console.

Comment: So you want, in the terminal, an ouptut to stdout which resembles (in terms of syntax coloring and other stuff) the way you would see the file in vim?

Comment: Why do you need this btw? I think it should be good enough to just use cat for this.

Comment: @Enrico, yes that's the idea. My current vim settings also remembers the last position where I edited a file so that would be another reason for actually using vim for the preview.

Comment: @wlisrausr, I'm writing a simple file navigation tool using fzf and I want to be able to preview it on the terminal before the user actually selects a file, ideally it preview should look exactly like it would on vim.

Comment: @Chubiduby, a preview of a text file is just a view on that file by means of a text **viewer**, and you call it _pre-_ just because you possibly look at it before opening the file in a text **editor**. Since you are talking about a **preview**, what could you ever take from Vim (which is an **editor**) into the **viewer**? I can think of two things only: syntax coloring, and the portion of the file shown (since the file could be bigger than the screen). I'm pretty much sure that there are non-**editor** solutions for this.

Comment: Furthermore, Vim uses syntax coloring (syntactically different parts of the text are colored in different ways), which **is not** related to any "modification" of the text itself (_`while` is a keyword for flow control, therefore Vim uses a specific color for it_). Contrarywise, the colors you see on screen in the terminal are just the result of [interpreting some escape sequences](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting).

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/sharkdp/bat

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, downloaded immediately!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, consider https://github.com/sharkdp/bat, a cat with syntax-highlighted wings